# Can iOS MapBox use rectangle offline map in .mbtiles?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I'm trying to make an offline map using iOS MapBox SDK. It's easy to make square map (eg. 32x32 tiles) but for some reason it doesn't work when I try to make rectangle map (eg. 40x32 tiles). It loads but it shows only a small portion of the map or skips some tiles. It just doesn't look as it should.

My `.mbtiles` looks correct, I checked `.mbtiles` and specification and it doesn't mention that there might be any problem with non-square maps.

Although, `.mbtiles` that comes with MapBox offline example called `control-room-0.2.0.mbtiles` is also square so maybe it's not possible for some reason.

Does anyone have experience with something similar?

Answer (score 1):

A non-square region should work just fine -- there is no limit on this. One way to test your `.mbtiles` is to upload it to your [MapBox account](http://www.mapbox.com/plans/) and see if it works on a web map. It sounds like your MBTiles file might have issues.

Comment: I think I figured out what was wrong. Starting at zoom level 0 my tiles were 6x5, 12x10, 24x20 and 48x40. I added 3 more zoom levels 1x1, 2x2, 3x3 and it works now.
But now first 3 zoom levels are not divisible by 256 so tiles that are smaller than 256x256 are skewed and it doesn't look very nice. I could fill empty space with some color but I would prefer if there was some smarter solution.
Also QuickView plugin from TileMill on OS X seems to have some problem with displaying tiles on max zoom (it just doesn't show them) but uploaded .mbtiles to MapBox web works fine.

Comment: I have the same problem with Mapbox. My tiles are: 4x3, 8x6, 16x12 and i can get it working, best case scenario i have no warning about missing data, but i can see only half of the map. Could you share your solution?